# Question about MochaHost.com Hosting Plans

Tags: php, svn, web-hosting

This is not an advertising, I've just found this website (MochaHost) that offers a great things just for 3$/m like :

- 2 LifeTime FREE Domains
- UNLIMITED Space and bandwidth
- SVN (subversion) support
- SSH access
- PHP 5, Perl, Python, and Rails

I need to know if any of you had taken from them a hosting plans, what do you think about it?

Comment: Be careful to own your domain name. Some cheap hosting register the DNS in their name and when you want to go elsewhere, you have to buy "your" DNS entry. (I don't know if it is the case here)

Comment: If it seems too good to be true...

Answer (score 2):

Cheap prices mean cheap services; Never trust in *unlimited* things.

Maybe they give you unlimited bandwidth, but what about the minimum guaranteed bandwidth?

Professional hosting has a price.